# Is it possible to improve Markov Chain Monte Carlo performance by decomposing a Binomial Likelihood?

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Suppose that we have sampled $y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n}$ from a Binomial distribution $Bin(N,p)$. Also, let's assume that $p$ is known and our goal is to infer the unknown parameter $N$, with the use of the MCMC Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

---

$\underline{Model}$

Likelihood, $L(N|y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}Bin(y_{i};N,p)$

and prior distribution denoted as $p(N)$.

---

$\underline{Update \ Step}$

For the MH update step we have the fraction $\frac{p(N^{cand})L(N^{cand}|y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n})}{p(N^{old})L(N^{old}|y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n})}$,

where $N^{cand}$ is the proposed value of the parameter $N$.

---

Now let's assume that for the exact data set $y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{n}$ we know that each $y_{i}$ can be decomposed as

$$y_{i} = y_{i}^{(1)}+y_{i}^{(2)}$$

where those $y_{i}^{(1)}$ and $y_{i}^{(2)}$, can be regarded independent, and follow Binomial distributions $y_{i}^{(1)}\sim Bin(N^{(1)},p)$ and $y_{i}^{(2)}\sim Bin(N^{(2)},p)$ for which is also known that $N=N^{(1)}+N^{(2)}$.

So, in this latter case instead of using the Likelihood of the form $\binom{N}{y_{i}}p^{y_{i}}(1-p)^{N-y_{i}}$ we can use the Likelihood of the form $\binom{N^{(1)}}{y_{i}^{(1)}}p^{y_{i}^{(1)}}(1-p)^{N^{(1)}-y_{i}^{(1)}}\binom{N^{(2)}}{y_{i}^{(2)}}p^{y_{i}^{(2)}}(1-p)^{N^{(2)}-y_{i}^{(2)}}$.

(I'm not bothered into placing priors on $N^{(1)}$ and $N^{(2)}$ because their sum is equal to $N$ so I place a prior directly on $N$)

---

$\underline{Question:}$ My question is, if this additional information of $y_{i}^{(1)},y_{i}^{(2)}$ gives an additional improvement into the MCMC Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, or using either the first or later Likelihood representation give exactly the same results?

My intuition is that it will improve things because we have additional information for the $y_{i}$ but I do not know if it true.

Comment: At the risk of missing the point of the question, I feel compelled to ask: why wouldn’t you just compute the posterior of $N$ numerically? Even if $p$ were unknown, this would be super easy.

Comment: @guy You mean to use MCMC to calculate the posterior under both likelihoods and compare which one gives the closest results to the true value of $N$??

Comment: What I mean is that you can just compute $\pi(N \mid y_1, \ldots, y_n) = \pi(N) \, L(N \mid y_1, \ldots, y_N) / \sum_{k} \pi(N = k \mid y_1, \ldots, y_n) \, L(N = k \mid y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ by using a computer to compute the terms in the denominator. MCMC is only really useful for higher dimensional problems, if you have one or two parameters it is perfectly reasonable to just use non-simulation-based numerical methods.

Comment: @guy I see what you mean. Sure it could be done, but I want to discuss it inside an MCMC framework because this is a part of a "bigger" algorithm.

Comment: If you incorporate the decomposition of the $y_i$'s you are changing the posterior and hence the target of the MCMC algorithm.

Comment: @Xi'an But $y_{i}=y_{i}^{(1)}+y_{i}^{(2)}$ shouldn't remain the same?? I mean from the $\binom{N}{y_{i}}p^{y_{i}}(1-p)^{N-y_{i}}$ I can go to the decomposed case if I'm not mistaken? The Likelihood is not changing I think.

Comment: The "update step" presumably means the acceptance probability in the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, in which case the proposal density is missing in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posterior on $N$ is in the first case
$$\pi(N|y)\propto \pi_N(N) \frac{N!}{(N-y)!} (1-p)^y\tag{1}$$
and in the second case$$\pi(N|y_1,y_2) \propto \sum_{N_1=1}^{N-1}
\frac{N_1!}{(N_1-y_1)!} \frac{(N-N_1)!}{(N-N_1-y_2)!} (1-p)^y\pi_{N_1,N_2}(N_1,N-N_1)\tag{2}$$
Since
$$\pi_N(N) = \sum_{N_1=1}^{N-1} \pi_{N_1,N_2}(N_1,N-N_1)$$
there is no reason to believe that
$$\pi(N|y)=\pi(N|y_1,y_2)$$
holds in general. This sounds logical in that observing both $y_1$ and $y_2$ brings more information about $N$ than observing $y$ alone.

Comment: So, the posterior is not the same, I got that.  If we wanted to check how much the posterior $\pi(N|y_{1},y_{2})$  deviates from $\pi(N|y)$ or how much the information $y_{1},y_{2}$ contributes instead of using just the $y$, a way to do that empirically, I assume would be to create a simulation and compare the two posteriors based on a variety of $y_{1},y_{2}$ values?

Comment: There is no closed-form solution or a theory behind such an assumption?

Comment: That observing $y_{1}, y_{2}$ might bring more information about $N$, I want to check how much varies the posterior under the $y$ alone and under $y_{1},y_{2}$, in order to check what this additional information brings to the posterior (that as we said is different from $y$ alone)

Comment: The problem is that the Fisher information is not defined for integer parameters, otherwise a comparison of Fisher informations should show this inequality holds.

Comment: I see I see, thank you very much for the discussion!!